# A feature is still right-skewed after log scaling. How should it be normalized for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, feature-engineering, outlier, distribution

I've attached two images below of a heavily right-skewed feature - call it `x`.  I log scaled `x`, but it is still right-skewed and still has several outliers. What does this suggest about the type of distribution of this variable? And what transformations should be done on this feature for effective modeling?

(I tried two levels of log scaling - see below.)

[image: Histogram of log10(x)]

[image: Histogram of log10(log10(x))]

Comment: Normally the goal is to get a predictor into a range like $[0,1]$ or to have a mean of zero and variance of one. Why do you (seem to) want it to be Gaussian?

Comment: To try to apply the simplest model possible first - e.g. linear regression. There's only 6 raw features, and their univariate distributions all share this behavior.

Comment: There is no assumption about Gaussian predictor variables in linear regression. When there is a Gaussian assumption in linear regression, it is about the error terms, which are estimated by the residuals.